# Podio Auth. "Array ( [error_parameters] => Array ( ) [error_detail] => [error_propagate] =>.."

Tags: php, arrays, api, authentication, podio

Starting out with podio API going no where fast..

```
<?php
define("CLIENTID", "###");
define("CLIENTSECRET", "####");
define("APPID", "###");
define("APPTOKEN", "#####");
require_once 'podio/PodioAPI.php';
Podio::setup($clientid, $clientsecret);
if (!Podio::isauthenticated())
{
    try {
        Podio::authenticatewithapp($appid, $apptoken);
    }
    catch(PodioError $e) {
        die(printr($e->body));
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [errorparameters] => Array ( ) [errordetail] => [errorpropagate] => [request] => Array ( [url] => http://api.podio.com/oauth/token [querystring] => [method] => POST ) [errordescription] => Invalid value "" (string): must be integer [error] => invalidvalue ) 1
```

The issue is with

```
Podio::authenticatewithapp($appid, $apptoken);
```

Its not passing the data even though it was defined. I'm rusty coding and this is my first go with APIs.

Comment: Where do you set `$appid, $apptoken`?  Maybe you meant `APPID, APPTOKEN`?

Comment: define("APPID", "###");
define("APPTOKEN", "#####"); 

i tried that as well and didnt work either

Output:
Array ( [error_parameters] => Array ( ) [error_detail] => missing_client_id [error_propagate] => [request] => Array ( [url] => http://api.podio.com/oauth/token [query_string] => [method] => POST ) [error_description] => Missing parameter client_id [error] => invalid_client ) 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your $appid and $apptoken are not defined, and that is why you are getting the "" string, non integer error. You could set those with the approriate values. However, since you did define the constants APPID and APPTOKEN already, you could use those as shown here:

```
   Podio::authenticate_with_app(APPID, APPTOKEN);
```

(also I am not sure why you are referring to the podio methods and even print_r() without the underlines, so it should be is_authenticated(), I assume your actual code is not that way or it wouldn't work)